# Need return button to make 2 hits

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a return button in my dashboard, but I have noticed an issue with it.

If I make a submit (ex. Updating a user profile) the return button should make 2 returns (because the button should go back to the same place every time, eventough I have submitted / updating in the dashboard.

Hope that you are able to help me, with the issue. I am open, to all kind of solutions.

```
<a  onclick="history.back()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt" title="go back"></a>
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code here? This will help us to help you.

Comment: of caruse, I have updated the post with a snippet

Comment: Yeah.... need more than that. Thats about as helpful as the question text.

Comment: If the button should go back to the same place every time why not just write the `href` target of the anchor to direct to the correct place instead of doing a `history.back`?

Answer (score 0):

It's happens because when you submit your form, this handle a new page request and then the browser push a new item on your history stack.

Because this, when your first time on this page, when you yet not submited your form, the button back should be work correctly, but when you submit the form and then your page was reloaded and you click on you back button, this should refresh or return to the same page, but if you click again you will be send to the home page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

You can resolve this setting an fix url like this:

```
<a href="YOUR_DASHBOARD_URL" class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt" title="go back"></a>
```